# What is the role of run script in Build Phases in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, run-script

Can any one explain actual usage of run script in xcode 4.

1. what is the usage of run script.
2. which type of scripts we can add in run script.
3. when will execute the run script.
4. explain some of the example to write the run script.

can you give over all idea of run script in Build Phases in xcode 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can execute scripts during build.

2) Mainly sh scrips.

3) You can drag the phase where ever you like it.

4) Have a look at this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH11-SW1).

Comment: can u tell me example scenarios where exactly we can use

Comment: For example: copy files, tar files, compile modules in a different language, render images, resize or crop images, write files to a repository, send mail, write info to a txt file.... Basically everything the terminal is capable to do.

Comment: Thanks for giving the replay. can u tell some of the links on run script. basically i do not have any idea on run script please help me.

Comment: If you don't know what to do with 'run script' you don't need it. Period.